# Using map<int, Foo> instead of vector<Foo> to avoid pointer invalidation

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl, containers

Say I have a class `Foo`, and a container `vector<Foo> Foos`. 
The algorithms I use rely heavily on pointers to the elements of `Foos`, and I also need to add `Foo`s dynamically and to access elements of the container. The problem is that if I add too many elements to the vector, it may need to reallocate the elements, hence invalidating all the pointers to these elements. Would it make sense then to use something like `map<int, Foo>` instead of `vector<Foo>`?

Comment: A short example to demonstrate your problem would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::deque` has similar performance (and random-access) to vector, but does not invalidate pointers upon insertion.

It does invalidate pointers on deletion, though.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>`, so I still have a vector and I still have valid pointers wherever I need them no matter how they are positioned inside the vector.

Answer (score 2):

This answer focuses on how to prevent pointer invalidation from happening, while still sticking to `std::vector`.

#### Preallocating

If you know beforehand the maximum number of `Foo` objects that the vector can contain, you can simply reallocate the vector's buffer with the [`std::vector::reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) member function. This way, a reallocation of the objects won't happen and therefore the pointers to the `Foo` objects won't be invalidated.

#### Using a vector of pointers

Alternatively, you can use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>` instead of `std::vector<Foo>`. This way, even if the vector reallocates its elements, the address of the pointed `Foo` objects won't change since it will be the `std:unique_ptr<Foo>` objects the ones that will be reallocated, not the `Foo` objects. Therefore, the pointers to the `Foo` objects will still be valid.

---

The latter approach introduces an additional layer of indirection, and it is, therefore, less efficient than the former one.

Answer (score 2):

You have four possibilities:

- You use a non-invalidating container. That's your suggestion.
- You reserve sufficient space in the vector beforehand ([El Professor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57248553/2445184)). This only works when you know the maximum amount of `Foo`s in advance.
- You use a vector of (smart) pointers ([Michael Chourdakis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57245611/2445184)). This works as long as you do not need to use the pointers as iterators.
- You make no change to your `vector<Foo>`, but instead of pointers, you make your algorithm work with indices. This allows you to look at the element before and after (after checking the vector bounds), and the indices won't be invalidated by reallocations.